# python twisted - how to get client IP

Tags: python, dns, twisted

How can i get the IP address of clients that are connecting to this dns server.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.names import client, dns, server


def main():
    """
    Run the server.
    """
    factory = server.DNSServerFactory(
        clients=[client.Resolver(resolv='/etc/resolv.conf')]
    )

    protocol = dns.DNSDatagramProtocol(controller=factory)

    reactor.listenUDP(10053, protocol)
    reactor.listenTCP(10053, factory)

    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

Thank you in advance :P

Comment: I believe you'll need to call `trasnport.getPeer()` from within `DNSDatagramProtocol` which means you'll have to overload either factory or protocol objects. There maybe an easier way to do it (hence why I'm just commenting ;D). You could try going on the Twisted IRC and asking the question. They're fairly helpful with these kinds of questions

Comment: Nope, pretty much that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.names import client, dns, server

class PrintClientAddressDNSServerFactory(server.DNSServerFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print("Connection to DNSServerFactory from {}".format(addr))
        return server.DNSServerFactory.buildProtocol(self, addr)

class PrintClientAddressDNSDatagramProtocol(dns.DNSDatagramProtocol):
    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        print("Datagram to DNSDatagramProtocol from {}".format(addr))
        return dns.DNSDatagramProtocol.datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr)


def main():
    """
    Run the server.
    """
    factory = PrintClientAddressDNSServerFactory(
        clients=[client.Resolver(resolv='/etc/resolv.conf')]
    )

    protocol = PrintClientAddressDNSDatagramProtocol(controller=factory)

    reactor.listenUDP(10053, protocol)
    reactor.listenTCP(10053, factory)

    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jean-paul-calderone it works :)                                  Datagram to DNSDatagramProtocol from ('127.0.0.1', 44507)
Datagram to DNSDatagramProtocol from ('127.0.0.1', 49043)
Datagram to DNSDatagramProtocol from ('127.0.0.1', 42383)
Datagram to DNSDatagramProtocol from ('127.0.0.1', 54875)
Datagram to DNSDatagramProtocol from ('127.0.0.1', 37708)

Comment: i'm new to python twisted, I've been trying to understand twisted over a month now but the official documentation and books (twisted - network programming essentials) does not seem to be explaining things very well. Do you have any suggestion for me to pick up the pace ?

Comment: If you haven't seen Dave P's Krondo tutorial - http://krondo.com/in-which-we-begin-at-the-beginning/ - that's worth a look.  Some people find it a better fit for their learning style than the upstream docs or the published books.  #twisted on freenode (irc) is also a good resource.

Comment: thank you i'll check that out. can i come back to you if i need further assistance with twisted.